# How to stop Script Errors in TWebBrowser in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have to show a slide show containing javascript language using TWebBrowser Component in Delphi 2010.

While I am playing in IE Browser it doesn't show any errors.

But while running in delphi it shows script error messages.

I don't know javascript language, So I can't do any modifications in javascript code but can do in delphi code.

I need a help that how to stop showing script error messages and play the slide show continuously.

I have coded WebBrowser.Silent:=true  in code but it stops both error messages and slide show of images.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you tried setting the `silent` property value to `true`, like so `WebBrowser1.Silent := True;`?

Comment: Sounds like it's time to learn Javascript. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with RRUZ, `WebBrowser1.Silent := True;`, placed in your code should hide the errors popup...

Regarding the slide show which is stopped... I think the answer has been already posted here:
[How do I make TWebBrowser keep running JavaScript after an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566659/how-do-i-make-twebbrowser-keep-running-javascript-after-an-error)

Answer (score -1):

This can be difficult. Tchromium [Link](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) (now on bitbucket) provides a Chrome alternative to TWebbrowser

Comment: @Altar What has replaced it?  Why is it outdated?

Comment: TChromium was not updated in years.

Comment: I still have applications that use it and still compile.

Comment: It was just a note so people would know that the project is still in beta phase and was not updated since 2011. The latest supported version listed there is XE2.

Comment: I have updated the link to bitbucket which seems to be in ongoing maintenance. @SolarWind

Comment: @toby-new link also not working :(